# Vector Abstract Background # mesh grid 3d none uniform diamond style

Tags: vector, polygon

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hcxuwDKo6I

[image]

Is there a way to create such colored triangle grid/mesh structure in Latex (e.g. any packages for such a task)?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: `pgfplots` has a `patch` plot style ... maybe you can use this? But it depends on your data and what exactly you want to achieve. If this is only for a background, it might be easier just to randomly generate some coordinates and connect them.